# Extract information from a column and printing it on a separate, aligned column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to extract the year and print it on a separate new column, and keeping the new column aligned.

Here's the input file:

```
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980) 
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception (2010)
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas (1990)
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars (1977)
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai (1954)
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump (1994)
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix (1999)
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus (2002)
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en (1995)
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs (1991)
```

How can I get the years in a separate column like this?

```
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back                  1980
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring               2001
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest                                 1975
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception                                                       2010
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas                                                      1990
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars                                                       1977
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai                                            1954
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump                                                    1994
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix                                                      1999
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers                           2002
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus                                                  2002
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en                                                           1995
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs                                        1991
```

Comment: Maybe you could try something, and then come back with a real programming question. This is a Q&A site, not a "Work for me" site. Question should show research.

Comment: Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 5):

```
sed 's/)\s*$//' file|column -s '(' -t
```

would work on the given input and give you expected output.

tested here:

```
kent$  echo "0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980) 
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring (2001)
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest (1975)
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception (2010)
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas (1990)
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars (1977)
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai (1954)
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump (1994)
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix (1999)
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers (2002)
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus (2002)
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en (1995)
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs (1991)"|sed 's/)\s*$//'|column -s '(' -t
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back      1980
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring   2001
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest                     1975
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception                                           2010
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas                                          1990
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars                                           1977
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai                                1954
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump                                        1994
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix                                          1999
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers               2002
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus                                      2002
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en                                               1995
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs                            1991
```

Comment: Note: this expects film titles to not contain brackets, that is why I used a brace instead.

Comment: @sudo_O I noticed it, I mentioned "given input" also I did a small search on imdb for the title with `(`, no result found. so I just posted answer. :D

Comment: If you don't care about films with brackets then check @MiklosAubert answers, I only used this approach to be flexible for the film titles.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick hack to do it:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[()]/,"",$NF);$NF="{"$NF}1' file | column -s'{' -t 
0000000124 462910 8.8 Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back      1980
0000000124 698356 8.8 The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring   2001
0000000233 393855 8.8 One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest                     1975
0000000124 733447 8.7 Inception                                           2010
0000000233 411397 8.7 Goodfellas                                          1990
0000000123 519051 8.7 Star Wars                                           1977
0000000124 146841 8.7 Shichinin no samurai                                1954
0000000123 618195 8.7 Forrest Gump                                        1994
0000000123 680520 8.7 The Matrix                                          1999
0000000123 604519 8.7 The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers               2002
0000000233 309137 8.7 Cidade de Deus                                      2002
0000000232 548307 8.6 Se7en                                               1995
0000000232 459707 8.6 The Silence of the Lambs                            1991
```

`awk` is used to remove the brackets from the last field and insert a `{` character. The output is piped into `column` to build the table using `{` as the separator. I choose the `{` character as I thought it would be unlikely to occur any where else in the data, if this is not the case choose a different character.

If I was you I would also quote the film titles:

```
$ awk '{gsub(/[()]/,"",$NF);$NF="{"$NF;$4=q$4;$(NF-1)=$(NF-1)q}1' q='"' file | ..
0000000124 462910 8.8 "Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back"      1980
0000000124 698356 8.8 "The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring"   2001
0000000233 393855 8.8 "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest"                     1975
0000000124 733447 8.7 "Inception"                                           2010
0000000233 411397 8.7 "Goodfellas"                                          1990
0000000123 519051 8.7 "Star Wars"                                           1977
0000000124 146841 8.7 "Shichinin no samurai"                                1954
0000000123 618195 8.7 "Forrest Gump"                                        1994
0000000123 680520 8.7 "The Matrix"                                          1999
0000000123 604519 8.7 "The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers"               2002
0000000233 309137 8.7 "Cidade de Deus"                                      2002
0000000232 548307 8.6 "Se7en"                                               1995
0000000232 459707 8.6 "The Silence of the Lambs"                            1991
```

---

**A much better approach is to use a language like python.**

You can use the string function `rfind()` to calculate the padding. You should use the following script if you have `python`:

```
import os
import sys

try:
    n = int(sys.argv[2])
except IndexError:
    n = 78
try:
    if os.path.isfile(sys.argv[1]):
        with open(sys.argv[1],'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                pad = n - line.rfind("(")
                print line[:-7],' '*pad,line[-5:-1]
    else:
        print "Please provide a file."
except IndexError:
    print "Please provide a file."
```

Save it to a file such a `table.py` and run like:

```
$ python table.py file
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back        1980
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring     2001
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest                       1975
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception                                             2010
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas                                            1990
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars                                             1977
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai                                  1954
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump                                          1994
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix                                            1999
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers                 2002
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus                                        2002
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en                                                 1995
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs                              1991
0000000123  123456   9.9  The best file (of all time)                           2025
```

Notice the addition of the film:

```
0000000123  123456   9.9  The best file (of all time) (2025)
```

If you position of the release column needs increasing pass in the value as the second argument like so:

```
$ python table.py file 100
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution with `awk`, which works with your sample data :

```
$ awk -F\( '{printf("%-77s %d\n", $1, $2)}' movies.txt
```

Adjust the format to your liking (here, the year is positioned at column **78**. You can change that in the format specifier, for instance use `%-99s` if you want it to start at column 100.

Comment: This would have been my approach but I was trying make sure the solution would fall over for films with `(` in. +1 however as probably the best solution ignoring the caveat.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python 2.X solution:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3
$ echo "0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)" | python -c "import sys;s=sys.stdin.readlines()[0]; print '%s\t%s' % (s[:-7], s[-6:-2])"
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back    1980
```

If your strings in `tmpfile` then:

```
$ cat tmpfile | python -c "import sys;map(lambda i: sys.stdout.write('%s %s %s\n' % (i[:-8], ' '*(100-len(i)), i[-6:-2])), sys.stdin.readlines())"
0000000124  462910   8.8  Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back                      1980
0000000124  698356   8.8  The Lord of the Rings: The Fellowship of the Ring                   2001
0000000233  393855   8.8  One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest                                     1975
0000000124  733447   8.7  Inception                                                           2010
0000000233  411397   8.7  Goodfellas                                                          1990
0000000123  519051   8.7  Star Wars                                                           1977
0000000124  146841   8.7  Shichinin no samurai                                                1954
0000000123  618195   8.7  Forrest Gump                                                        1994
0000000123  680520   8.7  The Matrix                                                          1999
0000000123  604519   8.7  The Lord of the Rings: The Two Towers                               2002
0000000233  309137   8.7  Cidade de Deus                                                      2002
0000000232  548307   8.6  Se7en                                                               1995
0000000232  459707   8.6  The Silence of the Lambs                                            1991
```

Comment: Throwing a TAB in works for one line... How does that line up the column for multiple lines?

Comment: @MichaelKazarian there is a tiny problem. check out the 1st line in your output. :) there was an ending space in input.

Comment: No, you did't. TABs don't line up the release year in a column.

Comment: @sudo_O, I fix it, try again

Comment: @Kent It have been bug in copy-paste from this page.

Comment: @MichaelKazarian gdgd, I also added a python solution.